# Using an InsertionSort algorithm to sort an Array of Strings with null elements within them

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

The algorithm formulated here has a complexity of O(n^2) (insertion sort). The algorithm though gets a `NullPointerException` since there are `null` elements within the `String` array. How do I get my algorithm to sort an array with null elements? Algorithm below:

```
private void sortFlowers(String flowerPack[]) {
    // TODO: Sort the flowers in the pack (No need to display
    // them here) - Use Selection or Insertion sorts
    // NOTE: Special care is needed when dealing with strings!
    // research the compareTo() method with strings

    String key;

    for (int j = 1; j < flowerPack.length; j++) { //the condition has changed
        key = flowerPack[j];
        int i = j - 1;

        while (i >= 0) {
            if (key.compareTo(flowerPack[i]) > 0) { //here too
                break;
            }

            flowerPack[i + 1] = flowerPack[i];

            i--;
        }

        flowerPack[i + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `key` can be null, then you should change this condition:

```
key.compareTo(flowerPack[i]) > 0
```

To something like:

```
compareKeys(key, flowerPack[i]) > 0
```

And then add a `null`-safe check, like:

```
private int compareKeys(final String first, final String second) {
    if (first == null || second == null) {
        return 0; // TODO: 0, here?
    } else {
        return first.compareTo(second);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`compareTo()` is part of the `Comparable` interface. It doesn't have a defined behavior for comparing null to anything. It actually *can't* have that behavior because `a.compareTo(b)` and `b.compareTo(a)` need to be consistent. You can:

1) Implement a custom `Comparator` that knows how to compare nulls, then replace `key.compareTo(flowerPack[i])` with `myComparator.compare(key, flowerPack[i])`

2) [Not use nulls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

3) Since this looks like homework, rewrite the bit inside your `while` look to only use `compareTo()` if *both* `key` and `flowerPace[i]` are non-null. If either (or both) are null, you need special cases.